# Umbraco 7 Custom Property Editor Error

Tags: angularjs, customization, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to get a basic custom property editor sorted out for an Umbraco 7.0.1 solution but it looks like I've missed something somewhere because Angular can't recognise the controller function being called. I need another pair of eyes over this.

I've pretty much copied and pasted [the example provided on Umbraco's site](http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/tutorials/CreatingAPropertyEditor) to start with and was intending to flesh it out afterwards. Here's what I have so far:

**package.manifest**

```
{   
    //you can define multiple editors   
    propertyEditors: [      
        {
            /*this must be a unique alias*/ 
            alias: "AcuIT.Multidate",
            /*the name*/
            name: "Multidate Picker",
            /*the html file we will load for the editor*/
            editor: {
                view: "~/App_Plugins/Multidate/multidate.html"
            }
        }
    ]
    ,
    //array of files we want to inject into the application on app_start
    javascript: [
        '~/App_Plugins/Multidate/multidate.controller.js'
    ]
}
```

**multidate.html**

```
<div ng-controller="AcuIT.MultidateController">
    <textarea ng-model="model.value"></textarea>
</div>
```

**multidate.controller.js**

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("AcuIT.MultidateController",
    function () {
        alert("The controller has landed");
    });
```

Finally, here is the error I'm seeing in the browser console:

> Error: Argument 'AcuIT.MultidateController' is not a function, got
>   undefined
>       at Error ()

It's probably a name or a path I've missed somewhere but I can't spot it yet. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart app pool and refresh browser to include the files from the manifest

Comment: I'm running IIS Express on the dev box and I was pretty sure I'd done everything required to flush any cached content, but will try this again to be sure.

Comment: Browser cache. Bugger. Thanks, Per.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Cache clearing not working in my case. Can anybody suggest something else?